# Coordinate geometry - rewriting equations

Tags: geometry

I'm trying find the $x$ coordinate for a point on a line with gradient $m$ which intersects a point $(p,q)$. I'm trying to express $x$ in terms of the distance $d$ from point $(p,q)$. Are these equations actually correct?

$$y-q = m(x-p)$$
$$d^2=x^2+y^2$$
$$\sqrt{d^2-x^2}=m(x-p)+q$$

$$x=\frac{{\displaystyle \pm }\sqrt{d^2 m^2+d^2-m^2 p^2+2m p q-q^2}+m^2 p-m q}{m^2+1}$$

They don't look quite right to me because if $q$ was a large number, the value inside the square root would be negative. Similarly if $d$ was a small number, and $m$ was negative, the value inside the square root would also be negative. Am I missing something?

Comment: You have not defined the X you are trying to find, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Paul The last equation is supposed to solve $x$. With a known $d$, $m$, $p$ and $q$, $x$ can be solved using it. But that's the equation I'm having issues with.

Comment: But what is X? Your first two sentences don't say what it is.

Comment: @Paul $x$ is the value on the x-axis for a point on the line with gradient $m$ which intersects with a given point $(p,q)$. The distance between the point and point $(p,q)$ is given as $d$.

Comment: I would get $d^2=(p-x)^2+q^2$

Comment: You're looking for $x = p \pm \frac{d}{\sqrt{m^2 + 1}}$, which you can check by picking some values of $x$, $y$, $p$, $q$, and $d$, with $m = (y - q) / (x - p)$.  I'd explain how and why in an answer, but I refuse to log in, so I am no longer allowed to post answers.

Comment: @Paul Actually shouldn't it be $d^2 = (p-x)^2 + (q-y)^2$ instead?

Comment: Y is 0 if X is on the X axis.

Comment: @BlabbotheVerbose Got it! Noticed that I had to solve $d^2 = (p-x)^2 + (q-y)^2; y=m(x-p)+q$ for $x$. Thank you.

Comment: @Paul Got it. Thank you.